# Return column1 only if column 2 contains all zeros

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

In my t-SQL db, I have an ItemLocation table. It lists warehouses, storage locations *in* the warehouses, items stored in those locations, and the current qty on hand. See below -

[image]

A warehouse (whse) can have multiple locations, and a location can have multiple items. As you can see from the image, there are items within locations that have '0' qty_on_hand.

What I would like to do is write a query that only returns locations that have absolutely NO qty_on_hand. For example, the highlighted location in my image (01-00-00A) would not be present in the result set of the executed query because it contains items that *do* have quantity. I'm only interested in the locations that don't have any quantity for any item whatsoever.

```
SELECT  itemloc.*
FROM itemloc
WHERE itemloc.qty_on_hand = '0'
AND whse IN ('MW10','MW40','MW60')
ORDER BY whse, itemloc.loc
```

My query depicts qty_on_hand should = '0', but I don't want the qty_on_hand to equal '0', because then it will return every location that has an item with no inventory. I can't quite figure out what my query would look like for this situation.

Comment: Do you have a warehouse table? If so you'd need to use that as your base table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the qty can only be 0 or positive value, you can use aggregation to find if max value for that location is 0.

```
select loc
from itemloc
group by loc
having max(qty) = 0
```

if it can be negative too, then use min as well:

```
select loc
from itemloc
group by loc
having max(qty) = 0 and min(qty) = 0
```

If you want to get the other columns as well you can use :

```
select *
from itemloc
where loc in (
        select loc
        from itemloc
        group by loc
        having max(qty) = 0
        );
```

or window function:

```
select *
from (
    select
        i.*,
        max(qty) over (partition by loc) max_qty
    from itemloc i
) t where max_qty = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - Had to step away from my desk. Grouping by loc having max(qty) = 0 worked for me. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Anthony Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subset of any `whse`/`location` combo that has `qty_on_hand` > 0 (for any item), and return the results not included in that subset.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM itemloc a
LEFT JOIN (select distinct whse,location from itemloc where qty_on_hand <> '0') b
ON a.whse = b.whse
AND a.location = b.location
WHERE b.whse IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    itemloc
WHERE
    loc IN
    (
        SELECT      loc
        FROM        itemloc
        GROUP BY    qty_on_hand
        HAVING      SUM(qty_on_hand) = '0'
    )
```